# Volume growth of balls implies volume growth of spheres?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have a complete, non-compact Riemannian manifold $M$ such that the volume of balls around a fixed point $p \in M$ satisfies
$$\mathrm{vol}(B_R(p)) \leq v(R)$$
for some function $v$. Can we then conclude some bounds on the volume growth of spheres, i.e.
$$ \mathrm{vol}(\partial B_R(p)) \leq \tilde{v}(R)$$
for some other function $\tilde{v}$?

If this fails, under what additional geometric conditions can one obtain such a result?

Comment: I believe it is true to say that when the Gaussian curvature is $\ge 0$, and hence there are no conjugate points, one has $$\frac{d}{dR} (\text{vol}(B_R(p))) = \text{vol}(\partial B_R(p))$$

Comment: this is true if there is a lower bound on Ricci curvature .This goes under the name of Bishop-Gromov comparison theorem .See for example H Karcher's paper Riemannian Comparison Constructions .